# Starting a long-running process in cloud-init on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I'm trying and failing to start a long-running command on launch of an EC2 (Amazon Linux). It needs to run under the ec2-user account. This was my first attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Woot 1!' > /home/ec2-user/woot1.txt
pushd /home/ec2-user/my-app-dir
nohup sudo -u ec2-user /home/ec2-user/my-app-dir/my_process.py &
echo 'Woot 2!' > /home/ec2-user/woot2.txt
```

The key command I'm trying to run is the "nohup" line, to run my_process.py.

The shell script works when I run it as root from a shell, but when I supply it in user-data to ec2-run-instances and login to the instance, I see both woot1.txt and woot2.txt, but my_process.py is not running. What's more, my_process.py creates a log file when it runs, but there is no log file there (and no nohup.out either) when I supply the script as user-data to ec2-run-instances.

I've tried putting the same things in a cloud-init form as well, with the same results:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - echo 'Woot 1!' > /home/ec2-user/woot1.txt
 - pushd /home/ec2-user/my-app-dir
 - nohup sudo -u ec2-user /home/ec2-user/my-app-dir/my_process.py &
 - echo 'Woot 2!' > /home/ec2-user/woot2.txt
```

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: updated to show I have tried full path as well as relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the process was not running was that the Amazon EC2 Linux instance is Red-Hat like, and there is a bug/feature in those distros that a sudo command requires a tty. There is no tty attached to the environment when the cloud-init is processed, and so it fails.

One answer is to edit etc/sudoers and change the line

```
Defaults requiretty
```

to

```
Defaults !requiretty
```

There are other approaches, apparently, but this worked for me.

Comment: FYI this restriction has been removed in Fedora already https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147 and that means it's likely to be removed from RHEL releases at some point. But whether or not amazon will follow with its derivative, I've no remote idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is no shell attached to this command.

Instead of

```
- echo 'Woot 1!' > /home/ec2-user/woot1.txt
```

Try

```
- /bin/sh -c "echo 'Woot 1!' > /home/ec2-user/woot1.txt"
```

Comment: I must not have been clear. The "echo" commands run, but my_process.py is the line that is not executed.

Comment: Ah, what happens if you put the full path to nohup? /usr/bin/nohup or whatever the path is.

Comment: So that's a good question and I'll give it a go. For now, I've fixed the problem by taking another approach: adding the script to /etc/rc.local before saving the AMI. That seems to work.